# display:table-header-group does not work in Android webview

Tags: android, html, css, printing, android-webview

I have a long table which I want to print it. I need to repeat `<th>` on beging of every page so I use `<thead>`:

```
<table>
        <thead>
            <tr><th>heading</th></tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr><td>notes</td></tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody>
        <tr><td>x</td></tr>     
        <tr><td>x</td></tr> 
        <!-- more rows -->
        </tbody>
</table>
```

I search the web for repeating `<thead>` on each page and I found this css:

```
thead { display:table-header-group; }
tfoot { display:table-footer-group; }
```

so when I click print in firefox, I see the header on each page correctly, but when I open the document in Android and want to print it the header is not shown. Is there any solution or alternative way?
edit: this picture show my problem better:
[image: what I want]

Comment: Do you want each page to have the table header on top?

Comment: yes, in my example the word "heading" should come in every page. in firefox it comes but in android doesnt come